# How to manipulate an array by grouping items into arrays

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this array:

```
let obj = [ 
   { prop: 'a', val: 2 },
   { prop: 'a', val: 1 },
   { prop: 'b', val: 3 },
   { prop: 'b', val: 1 }
]
```

Let's say i want to get an array for each existing prop val:

```
let myArr = [ 
   [ { prop: 'a', val: 2 }, { prop: 'a', val: 1 } ]
   [ { prop: 'b', val: 3 }, { prop: 'b', val: 1 } ]
]
```

how would you do that by using high order functions?

Comment: how is this functional programming?

Comment: i thought map, reduce, and  filter where functional programming function, i ll edit the tag

Comment: i made it by using a for loop and i don't like it at all.

Comment: why am i getting downvoted? :O

Comment: no code, just some expectations.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumProps(arr) {
    const sum = arr.reduce((ac,cv) => {
        if (ac[cv] === undefined) ac[cv.prop] = ac[cv.prop] = cv.val;
        else ac[cv.prop] += cv.val;
    }, {});

    const res = [];
    for (const p in sum) {
        res.push({ prop:p, sum:sum[p] });
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the objects by looking for an object with same `prop` and update the value.

```js
var array = [{ prop: 'a', val: 2 }, { prop: 'a', val: 1 }, { prop: 'b', val: 3 }, { prop: 'b', val: 1 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = r.find(({ prop }) => prop === o.prop);
        if (temp) {
            temp.val += o.val;
        } else {
            r.push(Object.assign({}, o));
        }
        return r
}, []);

console.log(result);
```